# How to save spaces without newline inside a 'td' tag?

Tags: css

I am using

```
white-space: pre;
```

It saves spaces, but is also saves newLine symbols.

Here what I have:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

td {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John       </td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>2881 Habberton RD #WC89 Spring Dale

3107 E 18th AVE Tampa, FL 33605</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>3201 Attems CT Glen Allen, VA 23060</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can I except newLine symbols with css?

Comment: please add proper code. thansk

Comment: Hi Dimitry, could you show us what you have done so far and what seems to be the issue ?

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't.

Comment: question updated

Comment: So do you want `white-space: nowrap;` …?

Comment: @04FS, No, `white-space: nowrap;` skip both spaces and newLines. I want to skip only newLines

Comment: That’s not directly possible. Replace the spaces with non-breaking spaces instead (server-side, or via JS on the client.)

Answer (score 0):

Is that you want ?

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

td {
  white-space: no-wrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John       </td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>2881 Habberton RD #WC89 Spring Dale

3107 E 18th AVE Tampa, FL 33605</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>3201 Attems CT Glen Allen, VA 23060</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No. As you can see value "John       " has spaces and this spaces must be saved. With your edit this spaces will be removed. I want to remove only newLines

Comment: Ok, as @04FS say above you can't do that, you have to use `&nbsp;` to preserve white space.